# Ionic Angular input not updating until click when username/password loaded from ios keychain

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, keychain

I'm encountering a strange issue with ionic 3. I have the iOS keychain enabled for users when logging in on my app. It populates the values but only after they click the input after using keychain.

My input:

```
<input 
  name="login_email" 
  id="user-text-field" 
  autocomplete="username" 
  type="email" 
  class="input-no-bottom-border" 
  placeholder="Email" 
  (change)="socialLoginProvider.loginEmail = $event.target.value" 
  [(ngModel)]="socialLoginProvider.loginEmail"
>
```

Basically when they click the keychain button on the keyboard it goes as expected but once they return to the app the inputs are still blank until a user clicks one of them then it triggers `(change)` and updates the values allowing the user to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 3 was not detecting changes and is a known bug that's fixed in v4. In order to fix this I setup a function to detect changes on click. I used `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

`(tap)="createDetector()"`

```
detector;

detectChanges() {
  return setInterval(() => {
    this.changes.detectChanges();
  }, 500);
}

createDetector() {
  this.detector = this.detectChanges();
}

destroyDetector() {
  clearInterval(this.detector);
}
```

I use clearInterval on a method completion just to clean up the interval so it's not running constantly.

Comment: this not works for me, the detectChanges not update anything. In fact if is periodically checks the value of reactive input it shows empty until the input is clicked. Then the check returns filled input value